# Servlet: custom 401 page isn't triggered

Tags: tomcat, servlets

I've registered an error page:

```
<error-page>
    <error-code>401</error-code>
    <location>/WEB-INF/exceptions/401.jsp</location>
</error-page>
```

I trigger an error in my Servlet:

```
response.sendError(401, "message here");
```

401.jsp:

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8" isErrorPage="true"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    ...
    <body>
        <h1>Unauthorized (401)</h1>
        <p><%= exception.getMessage() %></p>
    </body>    
</html>
```

Unfortunately, only the 'generic' 401 page is displalyed.

I've restarted the application and Tomcat, but no change.

What am I missing?

** edit 0 **

I included the JSP file's code.

It appears that the issue is with the `<%= exception.getMessage() %>` code.  If it is removed, the custom page displays as expected.  If it is present, the 'generic' message is displayed.

I substituted this JSTL `${pageContext.errorData.throwable.message}`.  The custom 401 page is displayed, but the message is blank.

Comment: Solved: [What is the simplest way to display httpServletResponse.sendError(403, “My Message”) status from JSTL][1]

  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1104452/what-is-the-simplest-way-to-display-httpservletresponse-senderror403-my-messa

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK jsp should be in outside `WEB-INF` folder, otherwise you have to configure your jsp in web.xml with `<jsp-file>` tag. Try to put 401.jsp in outside `WEB-INF`.

Comment: Placing JSP in the WEB-INF is a good practice, as it keeps it from unauthorized access.  The problem is with the embedded code, not its location.