# Access Response.sendError() method's argument from JSP

Tags: servlets, tomcat7

If I send a HTTP status code and a message like

response.sendError(404, "message here");

how do I reference the message from the associated, error-handling JSP (marked w/ isErroPage=true)?

None of these approaches work:

- 
- ${pageContext.errorData.throwable.message}
- [How to get the message in a custom error page (Tomcat)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/995248/how-to-get-the-message-in-a-custom-error-page-tomcat)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answered: [What is the simplest way to display httpServletResponse.sendError(403, “My Message”) status from JSTL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1104452/what-is-the-simplest-way-to-display-httpservletresponse-senderror403-my-messa)

- scriptlet: `<%= request.getAttribute("javax.servlet.error.message") %>`
- EL: `${requestScope['javax.servlet.error.message']}`