# Is it possible to pass parameters through the Error-page tag in web.xml for tomcat web applications?

Tags: tomcat, web.xml

I'm trying to create a custom 404 page that attempts to find the given page a second location.  To do this I've added the following to web.xml:

```
<error-page>
    <error-code>404</error-code>
    <location>/error/404-cf-redirect.jsp?</location>
</error-page>
```

As well as calling this page I would like to pass the URI in so that the redirect can understand where the user was trying to get to and then another location can be attempted.

If this fails to go anywhere another 404 will be generated and the same jsp will deal with the failed request differently producing the correct error message.

Is it possible to pass the URI as some parameter?

Cheers,

Alexei Blue.

Comment: try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/995248/how-to-get-the-message-in-a-custom-error-page-tomcat

Answer (score 0):

In your "not found" error page, you just have to get this value from the request attributes:

```
request.getAttribute("javax.servlet.forward.request_uri")
```

That will include the original URI requested by the client. You can find out a lot of information about the original request by reading section 9.4 of the servlet specification (which can be found here: http://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/final/jsr315/index.html). The whole spec is worth a read and IMO required reading for anyone writing web applications.